# PHP <ul> <li> database

Tags: php, html, css, tags

I am tring to put the image, title and rating of each movie within the array in to a `<ul> <li>` but I can only get it to put the first movie, title and rating in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<?php
require_once 'init.php';
require_once 'sessionCheck2.php';

$query = $con ->query
("
SELECT movies.id, movies.image, movies.movie_name, AVG(user_movie_ratings.rating) AS rating
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN user_movie_ratings
ON movies.id = user_movie_ratings.movie_id
GROUP BY movies.id
");

$movieTitle = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  {
$movieTitle[] = $row;
}

?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <div id="h1">

        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <?php //include 'loginCheck.php';?>
            <?php include 'login.php';?>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id ="movies">

        <?php foreach($movieTitle as $movie):?>

            <?php echo "<ul> <li>" .'<img src="'.$movie->image.'"/>';?>

                <div class = "cFFF">
                <?php echo $movie->movie_name; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="s11 c999">
                    Rating: <?php echo round($movie->rating); ?>
                </div>
            <?php echo "</li> </ul>"; ?>

            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <div id="footer">
        This is the Footer
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yous put it on hold 13 hours ago even though it was answered below 19 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think logically about where you are opening the `<ul>` and `<li>` versus where you are closing them (i.e. whether it should be in the loop or outside, and obviously it should not be reversed for opening and closing, either both open and close go in the loop or outside it, not one in and one out) and fix the typo of `<?ul>` on the closing.

And don't do like `<ul><li><div></li></ul></div>`  You need to close tags in the order in which you opened them.  I.e. `<ul><li><div></div></li></ul>`

What I imagine you're trying to do:

```
<div id="movies">
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($movieTitle as $movie)
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<img src="' . $movie->image . '" />';
    echo '<div class="cFFF">' . $movie->movie_name . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="s11 c999">Rating: ' . round($movie->rating) . '</div>';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry the extra opening outside the loop were from testing I have removed them now and fixed the typo. I would say that they would have to be inside the loop so as they are added to each instance from the array

Comment: @McNoodles You probably really want the ul outside the loop and the li inside. Doing one ul with multiple lis makes a list. Doing a new ul for each li makes many independent lists with only one list item each.

Comment: Ok i will give that ago when you say within the loop you mean at the first echo or in the actual foreach

Comment: @McNoodles See my edit. This is what I think you're looking for. Also, notice how you don't have to constantly close and reopen the php blocks or use that VB-style syntax.

Comment: Well all I have to say to that is `Thank You Very Much` that did exatly what I was tring to get it to do, I never thought of doing a Div within an echo before (Free Drink from me is in the Post)

Answer (score 0):

You may also check by printing the output of $movieTitle array via using below php statement :

echo count($movieTitle);

Make sure your MySQL JOIN returns correct result.